# Allow website to interact with client PC via locally installed service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I'm currently working on a corporate intranet application. I want to be able to have users install a windows service or some sort of program that could interact with a ASP.NET website we are currently building.

The goal would be to click a button on the website and allow it to communicate  with the current user's computer, allowing me to create Outlook email drafts as well as other tasks only possible with a locally installed program.

How could I pull this off? Ideally we would need it to work across all browsers, or at the very least IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Create a "worker" program that runs locally and associate it with some file extension (eg. *.sbonskosky).

When your web application wants to send some work to the local program, have it generate a *.sbonskosky file which is downloaded using the browser and is "executed" by the associated program.  Similar to when the browser asks to "Open or Save" a PDF and you choose "Open", it launches Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

If you can restrict the client OS to Windows then ClickOnce is the way to go. It is supported by all major browsers.

Basically, you create a desktop app and let it be deployed from the server. When at the client side, the application can interact with all local components as it works on user priviledged locally.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar right now with our website and client computers. Basically what we have is a DLL that gets installed to each of our client computers through an installer. Then on our webpage, there is an applet that invokes the DLL through JNI. When the user clicks a certain button or link, the applet talks to a C++ DLL, that invokes a C# DLL to execute client code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an application running on user's machine, you can host a WCF service in that application and bind it to a particular port (say 44444). Then from your web application just send http requests to localhost:44444. So what happens is when the user clicks on a button on the web page it sends a request to a server running on the local machine. Hope this helps.

Comment: So the WCF service would be installed on each client's machine, which binds to port 44444? But if I send requests to localhost wouldn't it pass those requests to the web server, not the client's computer?

Comment: When the browser sends a request to localhost it goes to a service running on the local  machine (user's machine)